# How to change application language?

Tags: trailhead, setup

Is it possible to force the Trailhead platform to use English?

Currently when I use it, it's stuck in Italian, which it makes harder to follow the tutorials.

**EDIT**

Sorry people, maybe I did non explain myself correctly but I want to change the language of this application:

[image: SF_setup]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change the language for your own login:

1. Click on:

a. (Classic) Setup | Personal Setup | My Personal Information | Edit

b. (Classic; Improved Setup) Your name | My Settings | Personal | Language & Time Zone

c. (Lightning Experience) Your Avatar | Settings | Language & Time Zone

2. Change the Language drop-down to the language you want.
3. You may also want to modify your Locale setting to control the formatting of numbers, dates, and phone numbers.
4. Click "Save".

If you want to standardize your entire company on a particular language and locale, an administrator will need to modify or translate some global data for the organization:

- Click on Setup | Administration Setup | Company Profile | Company Information | Edit and change the Default Language, Default Locale, and Currency Locale. All new users will inherit these Language and Locale settings.

[change to a different language for Salesforce](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000005218&language=en_US&type=1)

Comment: why this answer is downvoted?

Answer (score 5):

Go to your Profile

[image]

At the bottom right of the page you can change your language
[image]